# Firebase functions https.onRequest to await a field change

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Trying to get my response to an https.onRequest function to contain a value from a field that is being created by another cloud function (onCreate) once the request is received, but can't seem to get it working.

Here is my function which I need to wait for the field to update and then responde with it. I am using a bit of a workaround here - with manual timeouts. Not sure if there are better ways of getting the field's value once it's there?

```
let val2;
 let getSchedule = async () =>
        await admin
          .firestore()
          .collection("bookings")
          .doc(newBooking.id)
          .get()
          .then(async (snap) => {
            if (!snap.exists) {
              await new Promise((r) => setTimeout(r, 1000));
              return await getSchedule();
            } else {
              val2 = snap.data();
              if (val2.schedule) {
                return val2.schedule;
              } else {
                await new Promise((r) => setTimeout(r, 1000));
                return await getSchedule();
              }
            }
          });
      let val = await getSchedule();
      return { result: "OK", schedule: val };
```

Anyone know how to respond with a field's value once it's created by the request?

Comment: Why do you need to do this? Are you sure this is the right thing to do for whatever problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: isn't it possible you use onUpdate trigger ?

Comment: @DougStevenson possibly not, but I don't know else to return the requested data to an api call? Logic is simple - https request with some input => processing => response with some output

Comment: @Ashish I was thinking that too, but not sure if you can nest onUpdate inside of an https.onRequest. Haven't found any examples of that and my own attempt at implementing that didn't quite work because response wasn't waiting for the onUpdate to happen

Comment: The part that I'm confused about is your requirement that it get a "value from a field that is being created by another cloud function".  Are you saying this other value doesn't exist yet and it needs to wait for it to exist?  Why does it need to wait?  What's really going on here?  The question makes it sound more complicated than just getting existing data (which is a really easy problem to solve).

Comment: Doug - yes, that value doesn't exist when the request is made. it's a fairly simple use case: 1) a post request hits an endpoint with some data, 2) that data is used to generate a file which takes more than a few seconds and then store it in storage, 3) the link to that file in storage is included into the response to the post request. Do you know of a better way of doing it?

Comment: I don't think this would work in the way you are planning, a better way would be to create a function that is triggered when the file is created in GCS, which is possible and you can find more details in [here](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/storage), would this work for your problem?

Comment: @RafaelLemos this solution wouldn't fit here because the function wouldn't know what to do with the file. But I'm using my workaround for now. I just add a timeout to wait for the file to be written and then it responds. If anyone has any better idea how to do it, let me know.

Comment: In that case, maybe the ideal would be to store the information that your first function holds somewhere, like Firestore, so that the second event function triggered by the storage fetches it when the file is ready. What do you think?